# Why does my slash command require me to input CTX as a required field?

Tags: pycord

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from datetime import datetime
from discord import Option


class Secondary(commands.Cog):
  def __init__(self, client):
    
    self.client = client
    
    @client.slash_command(description = "")
    async def avatar(self, ctx, user: Option(discord.Member, "Choose a user to mention.")):
      AvatarEmbed = discord.Embed(
        title = f"{user}'s profile image.",
        color = discord.Colour.dark_green()
      )
      AvatarEmbed.set_image(url = user.avatar.url)
      AvatarEmbed.timestamp = datetime.utcnow()
      await ctx.respond(embed = AvatarEmbed, ephemeral = False)
    
def setup(client):
  client.add_cog(Secondary(client))
```

The code above is what's in my cog.

So I'm trying to make a "avatar" command to display the selected users profile picture. I'm not sure why but it keeps forcing me to enter "ctx" as a field.
[Here](https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/1009087513052336320/1020114969427193916/unknown.png?width=248&height=85)

Answer (score 0):

It's in a cog, but you're registering it using `client.slash_command`. That ignores the implicit `self` argument of a bound method and makes it register with `self` as the context argument, instead of `ctx`. Simply decorate it with [`commands.slash_command`](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/api.html?highlight=slash_command#discord.commands.slash_command) instead:

```py
@commands.slash_command(description = "")
async def avatar(self, ctx, user: Option(discord.Member, "Choose a user to mention.")):
      ...
```

Comment: Honestly I'm not sure how I missed that, thank you. I made the necessary correction to the code that you highlighted but now it wont even show up in the slash commands menu.

Comment: You could also try changing it back to `client.slash_command` but then remove the `self` and remove it from the cog. Also make sure you've updated.

Comment: Well gosh... I'll try moving it to my main file but I'd really like to keep it as a slash command.